# Using different client code base for a meteor app for cordova and website

Tags: angularjs, cordova, meteor, ionic-framework

I know there are other (rather old) questions on this subject but I haven't seen any answer with meteor 1.0. I am building an app targeting both mobile and desktop.

I ported an existing mobile client created with ionic and it's working great. Now I would like to setup the desktop client part and don't want to add "if (Meteor.isCordova) {" clauses everywhere. I could share some of my custom Angular directives or services but Ionic is mobile targeted only so I want clear code separation.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Might be able to help but I'm confused about your setup. Are you using Meteor and Ionic/Angular for the mobile app? And then just Meteor (with no Ionic/Angular) for the desktop? Could you give more details please? You could potentially check for Meteor.isCordova on page load and then depending on the outcome `angular.bootstrap()` a different Angular module, but I may be misunderstanding your question completely.

Comment: I am using ionic-meteor to develop the mobile app (already working) and I would like to use angular-meteor only (no ionic) for desktop. I won't share any temlpates between platform so I would like to have dedicated folder for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a package for the shared logic and have two different meteor projects or packages? One for web (e.g. meteor+bootstrap) and the other for mobile (e.g. meteor+ionic)?

Perhaps something like this: https://github.com/Compy/meteor-mobile-desktop

Comment: Thanks Humber ! From what I've seen it is the cleaner solution. I am trying now and it seems desktop package is properly isolated from mobile one. This means that I don't end up with all desktop files loaded in the the mobile app : exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Awesome @jpwizer. I'm glad this solution is useful to you. To be fair, the credit is mostly for https://github.com/Compy

Comment: Great solution. What's annoying about it is that you can't use the command line to add the packages you need anymore. You've always got to be messing with the package.js files. But there's probably no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like what I have below. The basic idea is to have three angular modules. One main module will have all your shared angular code that is common across the desktop and mobile versions. Then you need another two modules, one each for the desktop and mobile versions that have the main module as a dependency.

You only need to run `Meteor.isCordova()` once when the page loads the first time. Depending on the outcome, you can then bootstrap the main module and either the desktop or mobile version.

This means that you only load things that you need in each version. E.g. I haven't done it because the snippet won't run, but you should inject Ionic into the mobile module only if it is not being used in the desktop application.

Apologies if I am misunderstanding your setup, but it's hard to figure out without seeing it.

```js
// Module for web and mobile application (common functionality).
angular.module('App', []);

// Module for web application.
angular.module('WebApp', ['App'])
  .controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the web application.';
  });

// Module for mobile application.
angular.module('MobileApp', ['App'])
  .controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is the mobile application.';
  });


(function () {
   
  // Simulate Meteor.isCordova().
  var isCordova = true;
  
  // Bootstrap correct version of the application.
  if (isCordova) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['App', 'MobileApp']);
  } else {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['App', 'WebApp']);
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as it gives a nice way to manage my angular code. But my question is not only for angular js code but also for views, routes etc... Unfortunatly as for @Eliezer solution both desktop and mobile will load full templates and code.

Answer (score 0):

I've also asked this question before and didn't get an answer.

You could use two different routers. One for Web and one for mobile. That way you'd only need one if isCordova statement. 
Then just separate the web and mobile client side files into different folders.

Comment: Sure I could do that but It would load all my desktop website on mobile. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yeah. It would I think. More annoying would be it loading all your mobile stuff on your website I think. On the mobile it'd just be a one time download. Website would download all mobile stuff for each new visitor