# How to get from zero to Mobile Web App with Data in 60 seconds

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, meteor, mobile

I know that all these components exist, however I really am trying to figure out if someone has brought all these together.

Here is what I need:

- JavaScript/NodeJS core application boilerplate/framework
- With a website, HTML app (aka PhoneGap or even better Ionic), and ideally option to add something like a desktop app (like electron) client flexibility
- All with possibility of different/specialized frontend code so all assets and HTML could be packaged into the app
- Ideally kept in one GIT repo
- With shared code amongst all UIs
- Ability to use Angular 2 in all environments (or something similar)
- Realtime? standardized data connection with data source (like meteor's DDP), I really dislike polling and I don't want to have to write my own data protocol
- Have some kind of authentication capacity
- Already exist in some way

What I have been eyeballing thus far is Ionic2 on top of Meteor, however it is remarkably difficult to find an actually working example of them playing together and I have not found any with separate codebases between the two interfaces.

To clarify, below is sort-of what I envision for a folder structure:

```
public/
common/
    models/
    business-logic/
server/
web/
desktop/
mobile/
```

And in that, all UIs and server can import from the common folder.

The end goal is to have something like Slack where they have 3 different ways of accessing the same data using the same rules but can really specialize in each interface type.

Does this exist?

I am really looking to have something that can be started with:

```
git clone http://github.com/a/bc
npm install
# do some other things that are documented
meteor run ios
```

Or am I not gonna have my cake and be able to eat it too?

I know I am shooting for the moon, but I know I can't be the first person looking to do this

Comment: Found this comment on how to separate environments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101559/using-different-client-code-base-for-a-meteor-app-for-cordova-and-website

Answer (score 1):

For the backend I think that [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/) may be a good bet if you want fast developement.

They have some examples for iOS, Android and Angular apps on their website:

[image]

You may get some ideas from [their documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/) or [several example projects on GitHub](https://github.com/strongloop).

LoopBack is currently backed by IBM.